# How can i select dates programmatically and show on FSCalendar

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa, fscalendar

I used FSCalendar(https://github.com/WenchaoD/FSCalendar) in my project. If user click repeat button, the events repeats everyday. I want to show it on calendar which is in my application. How can I do it?

Comment: first read about Eventkit. you can check this link for tutorial-> https://www.raywenderlich.com/64513/cookbook-making-calendar-reminder.

Comment: you understand me wrong. I want my own reminder application with using FSCalendar.

Answer (score 7):

If you want to select date then below method will be helpful,
where calendar is outlet of FSCalendar.

`calendar.select(calendar.today)`

And if you want to select multiple dates then the best way would be to use event dots, and that can be possible through below delegate method of FSCalendar Data source,

`func calendar(_ calendar: FSCalendar, numberOfEventsFor date: Date) -> Int
{
//number of dots you want to show
}`

or if you really want to show dates selected, you can use below method smartly and returning different colours for dates that you want to select,

```
    public func calendar(_ calendar: FSCalendar, appearance: FSCalendarAppearance, fillDefaultColorFor date: Date) -> UIColor?
{
    if your date
    {
         //return the colour for your dates
    }
    else
    {
         //return default colour
    }
}
```

Hope, this answer helps you.

Comment: Make sure you confirm FSCalendarDelegateAppearance :)

Comment: And if we want to deselect them, it will create problem

Answer (score 0):

For Remainder app you need to do or use following thing.

1.Realm or Core Data - for Data persistency.

2.local notification - to notify user that some event is occured.
you need to use **UILocalNotification** that have one property **fireDate** property.

Comment: I dont want to give an notification, I want to show on calendar which is in my application. I use FSCalendar. https://github.com/WenchaoD/FSCalendar.

Comment: your problem is how to display it in calendar...?

Comment: FSCalendar have a method calendar(calendar: FSCalendar, didSelectDate date: NSDate) on selection you can display it or you can simply do it using tableView.Display your reminder in tableview.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know how you're persisting that information (the scheduled date), what i can tell you is that you can easily add a *dot* (or more if you'd like, just change the number) with the following delegate:

```
`func calendar(calendar: FSCalendar, numberOfEventsForDate date: NSDate) -> Int {
    let formatter = NSDateFormatter()
    formatter.dateFormat = "MM-DD"
    let date1 = formatter.stringFromDate(yourDate)
    let date2 = formatter.stringFromDate(date)
    return date1 == date2 ? 1 : 0
}`
```

This method is one of FSCalendar delegates and it iterates all days in the current month (each one of them represented in `date` variable). In the example above i'm comparing if the any given date is equal to *yourDate* variable which has to be a `NSDate` as well by transforming both of them into Strings via `NSDateFormatter` in *Month-Day* format so the comparison is equal for all months. If true, return 1 (this indicates 1 dot, you may change it for more if you want to), otherwise return 0 dots below the specific date.

This code is Swift 2.3 compliance.